# Cannot hide programmatically created UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

This issue is baffling me for a few days now.

I have 2 UIButtons, one created using the Storyboard and one created programmatically.

When I press one of the buttons, I am moved to a method that hides both the programatically built and storyboard buttons, but only the storyboard button disappears, whereas the programmatically built button remains. I have tried not only hiding but also changing the frame of the programmatically built button, but to no avail.
Here is the code used:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *catBut;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *whenButton;
....
....
-(void)viewDidLoad {
....
    [self customizeButton:self.catBut withFrame:CGRectMake(165, 113, 135, 50)
          andAction:@selector(selectedCat) andColor:[UIColor belizeHoleColor] 
          andTag:2 andImage:@"coffee-64.png" andText:@"Cafes" andAlignmentLeft:YES];
....
}

- (void)customizeButton:(UIButton *)but withFrame:(CGRect)rect andAction:(SEL)action
                        andColor:(UIColor *)col andTag:(NSUInteger)tag 
                        andImage:(NSString *)imageName 
                        andText:(NSString *)buttonText 
                        andAlignmentLeft:(BOOL)alignLeft {
    but = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [but setFrame:rect];
    [but setTitle:buttonText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    but.tag = tag;
    but.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    but.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldFlatFontOfSize:18]; 
    [but setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    CGFloat spacing = 10; // the amount of spacing to appear between image and title
    but.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    but.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, spacing, 0, 0);
    but.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, spacing*2, 0, 0);
    [but setTitleColor:[UIColor cloudsColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [but setTitleColor:[UIColor cloudsColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [but addTarget:self action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.buttonsView addSubview:but];
}
....
- (void)selectedCat {
    self.catBut.hidden = YES;
    self.whenButton.hidden = YES;
}
```

Why is only the Storyboard button compliant to UI changes? Is there something I am missing? I have tried cancelling the AutoLayout but that didn't change a thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the passing for argument in your method (`customizeButton:(UIButton *)but`).

Change your code to this and check

`but = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];`

to

```
   self.catBut = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
......
[self.buttonsView addSubview:self.catBut];
```

OR You should pass the address `customizeButton:(UIButton **)but` in the method

and while calling use `&self.catBut`

Comment: I had a hunch it was something to do with the passing of the UIButton pointer.

Comment: Wow, that is horribly annoying. Was wracking my brain. Because I always do skipButton = [[skipButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width/2-skipButtonImage.size.width/4.0, 966.0/2.0, skipButtonImage.size.width/2, skipButtonImage.size.height/2.0)]; that's so annoying.

Answer (score 0):

It is **BOOL** type, not an `bool` type.

try this

```
self.catBut.hidden = YES;
self.whenButton.hidden = YES;
```

I can see this property `catBut`, But I cann't see creation for this, as well I didn't give Outlet too. Check this. You've tried something but simply fix by following line.

```
[self.buttonsView addSubview:but];
self.catBut = but;
```

Comment: Thanks iMani, but thats not the issue. Ill modify the code accordingly.